# What are side boxes properly called?

Tags: page-layout, terminology

What is the correct name for aside boxes that text has to flow around?

For an example of what I mean, please look at [this article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/08/opinion/in-new-orleans-racisms-history-is-harder-than-stone.html). I'm talking about boxes like the one that starts with "Sign Up for the Opinion Today Newsletter".

---

[image]

Answer (score 11):

[Pull quote, Lift out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_quote), or [Callouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callout) are common terms. Which term is most fitting is somewhat dependent upon the *content* of the "box".

> A **pull quote** (also known as a lift-out pull quote) is a key phrase, quotation, or excerpt that has been pulled from an article and used as a graphic element, serving to entice readers into the article or to highlight a key topic. It is typically placed in a larger or distinctive typeface and on the same page. Pull quotes are often used in magazine and newspaper articles, annual reports, and brochures, as well as on the web. They can add visual interest to text-heavy pages with few images or illustrations.

-

> In publishing, a **call-out or callout** is a short string of text connected by a line, arrow, or similar graphic to a feature of an illustration or technical drawing, and giving information about that feature. The term is also used to describe a short piece of text set in larger type than the rest of the page and intended to attract attention.

However in your example, it's merely an **advertisement**, unrelated to the rest of the page content.

Comment: "Pull quote" seems wrong in this instance, but "call-out" is more appropriate.

Comment: In cases where this ‘lifted’ content around which the copy flows is a larger area (perhaps even an entire page or spread), I have sadly had to accept the rather unsatisfying conclusion that [English has no appropriate term](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334021/word-for-a-vignette-on-a-specific-topic-within-a-book).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ------ [Sidebar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidebar_(publishing)) Ha... posted this comment before looking at your link, which states Sidebar as well.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure there is an official name, as these can include a number of things like notes, lists, quotes, highlights, etc, but generally I would call these *inserts*.

Comment: I +1'd you, but *insert* is often *also* used for loose (not bound) material to be inserted into a publication. Probably the better term is an *inset*. I have heard both used for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It's a *sidebar.*

> a short article in a newspaper or magazine, typically boxed, placed alongside a main article, and containing additional or explanatory material.

https://www.google.com/search?q=define+sidebar

Comment: This is misleading. A sidebar tends to imply something that takes up a full column alongside the main part of an article, not a part of the text section as shown in the question

Comment: Definitely _not_ a sidebar. That sits usually on the SIDE and is not flown with the main article content.

Comment: Actually I would disagree with comments. +1 for the answer. Writers **often** use the term "sidebar" to mean "separate but related content" which should be included, but not part of primary content. It's more akin to a legal "sidebar" than a web dev "sidebar".  Related discussion but not imperative to the primary topic. WebDev "sidebars" refer to *placement* far more than content.

Answer (score 1):

it's a "call for action box or paragraph".

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to add some references to back you up? where did you get this term from?